# iMessages between two devices are received by the device sending the message

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

When my husband sends me an iMessage from his iPhone 5c it sends it to him. If I send him a message from my iPhone 5c it send it to me. This has just happened since we updated yesterday.

Comment: Are you sure the iCloud/iMessage email account are set correctly on the contacts ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same Apple ID or the same cellphone number to receive iMessages on both iPhones' iMessage clients. Doing so will lead to you receiving your own sent message, like I am:

[image]

Here's a quick fix:

1. Open Settings>Messages.

[image]

2. Tap "Send & Receive".

[image]

3. Tap "Add another Email".
4. Type a diiferent email ID. It will now show a "Verifying..." status. Open that e-mail inbox and confirm verification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably happening because you are either using the same account on both devices or you have the same phone numbers or email addresses registered on each account.